# Second router can't access addresses when a main router routes over it

Tags: linux, networking, routing, bsd

I have a main BSD router (A) routing some subnets via a second Linux router (B) and everything works fine.
But when I try to access those subnets from the second router, it doesn't work. It sounds like return packets are discarded or not being routed correctly?

I assume it looks like: request from B (A is a default gw) -> A decides to route via B -> ...struggling there...

Just in case: a list of subnets on A is dynamic, so I can't keep a copy of it to override routes on B.

### A (OPNsense)

`ifconfig`:

```
ix0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
 options=4803828<VLAN_MTU,JUMBO_MTU,WOL_UCAST,WOL_MCAST,WOL_MAGIC,NOMAP>
 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
 media: Ethernet autoselect (10Gbase-Twinax <full-duplex,rxpause,txpause>)
 status: active
 nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
igb0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
 description: WAN (wan)
 options=4802028<VLAN_MTU,JUMBO_MTU,WOL_MAGIC,NOMAP>
 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
 inet xx.xx.100.162 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast xx.xx.101.255
 inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%igb0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2
 groups: IG_WAN
 media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
 status: active
 nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
igb1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
 description: WAN2 (opt7)
 options=4802028<VLAN_MTU,JUMBO_MTU,WOL_MAGIC,NOMAP>
 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
 groups: IG_WAN
 media: Ethernet autoselect
 status: no carrier
 nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
enc0: flags=0<> metric 0 mtu 1536
 groups: enc
 nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
 options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
 inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
 groups: lo
 nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
...
ix0_vlan4: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
 description: SERVICE (opt4)
 options=4000000<NOMAP>
 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
 inet 192.168.4.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.4.255
 groups: vlan IG_BROADCAST IG_SRV_ACCESS IG_WAN_ACCESS
 vlan: 4 vlanproto: 802.1q vlanpcp: 0 parent interface: ix0
 media: Ethernet autoselect (10Gbase-Twinax <full-duplex,rxpause,txpause>)
 status: active
 nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

`netstat -rn` (xx.xx - WAN addresses):

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            xx.xx.100.1        UGS        igb0
8.8.4.4            192.168.4.58       UGHS   ix0_vlan
xx.xx.1.2          xx.xx.100.1        UGHS       igb0
xx.xx.1.4          xx.xx.100.1        UGHS       igb0
xx.xx.100.0/23     link#2             U          igb0
xx.xx.100.162      link#2             UHS         lo0
127.0.0.1          link#5             UH          lo0
127.0.1.1          link#14            UH          lo1
...
192.168.4.0/24      link#11            U      ix0_vlan
192.168.4.1         link#11            UHS         lo0
```

### B (Debian)

`ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s18
    inet 192.168.4.58/24 metric 1024 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global dynamic ens18
       valid_lft 85211sec preferred_lft 85211sec
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 198.18.0.1/15 brd 198.19.255.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip r`:

```
default via 192.168.4.1 dev ens18 proto dhcp src 192.168.4.58 metric 1024
192.168.4.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.4.58 metric 1024
192.168.4.1 dev ens18 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.4.58 metric 1024
198.18.0.0/15 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 198.18.0.1
```

`ip r s t 1000`:

```
default via 198.18.0.1 dev tun0 proto static
198.18.0.0/15 dev tun0 proto static scope link
```

`ip ru`:

```
0: from all lookup local
32765: from all iif ens18 lookup 1000 proto static
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
```

`tun0` is being created via [github.com/xjasonlyu/tun2socks](https://github.com/xjasonlyu/tun2socks):

```
ip tuntap add mode tun dev tun0
ip addr add 198.18.0.1/15 dev tun0
ip link set dev tun0 up
tun2socks -loglevel info -device tun0 -proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

### Notes

- Spotted the following from syslog when trying to access `8.8.4.4` (for example) from B (when it's routed on A via `192.168.4.1`): `IPv4: martian source 8.8.4.4 from 192.168.4.58, on dev ens18`
- Tried `ip rule add iif lo lookup 1000 suppress_prefixlength 0` as suggested by @A.B but it didn't work.

Comment: @A.B Sure, added more details. B basically just redirects its incoming traffic to an interface `tun0`.

Comment: Removed LL addresses, thanks for pointing. Also tried `suppress_prefixlength` but it didn't change anything: everything works from other hosts in the network but doesn't from B. Also verified it works fine if I explicitly route anything to `tun0` on B but I can't adopt it since a dynamic list of networks is on A.

Comment: @roaima Sounds good, done.

Comment: I see that (A) and (B) both have default routes. Where is the NAT (masquerading) taking place?

Comment: NAT is on A (from `igb0` to `ix0_vlan4`).